# AWS RDS PostgreSQL - copying from/to csv files on EC2 instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, psql, trifacta

I've run into problem that I can't fix for a few days.

The thing is - I have following architecture:

- Two EC2 instances which are nodes running Trifacta application (some kind of application for data scientists),
- AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance.

Since the newest version this `Trifacta` application is using new schema in database which performs some database migrations at the start of application. During the startup some tables are copied into *.csv files and then copied back into tables from this *csv files.
It's all okay when it's run on local database because `superuser` role in postgresql allows for such actions.
When it comes to performing it on AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance it falls in following errors:

```
Error running query COPY (select "id" from workspaces) TO '/tmp/workspaces.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER; error: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
    at Connection.parseE (/opt/trifacta/migration-framework/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:614:13)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/opt/trifacta/migration-framework/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:413:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/trifacta/migration-framework/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:129:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  length: 178,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42501',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: "Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \\copy command also works for anyone.",
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'copy.c',
  line: '905',
  routine: 'DoCopy'
}
```

It's just first one, there are a lot of them. I made a research on that and figured why it's happening. AWS is using `rds_superuser` role instead of `superuser` and privilleges of this role aren't sufficient for copying from/to local filesystem.
From psql console it can be done with using `\copy` instead of `copy` but in my case it isn't any helpful because the way Trifacta does it is executing SQL queries from their *.js files and as far as I know it isn't possible to run `\copy` query from anywhere else than `psql CLI`.

With a suggestion of @IMSoP I am adding the code of Trifacta *.js file where the actions are performed:

```
ConnectUtils.copyQuery = function(query, connection, options = {}) {
  ensure.notNull(connection.base.DriverName, 'connection driver name');
  ensure.notNull(options.tableName, 'table name');
  const table = options.tableName;
  const filePath = ConnectUtils.getOutputFilePath(table, options);
  if (connection.base.DriverName === DATABASE_JS_TYPE[MYSQL]) {
    return `${query} INTO OUTFILE \'${filePath}\' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`;
  } else if (connection.base.DriverName === DATABASE_JS_TYPE[POSTGRES]) {
    return `COPY (${query}) TO '${filePath}' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;`;
  } else if (connection.base.DriverName === DATABASE_JS_TYPE[SQLITE]) {
    return query;
  }
  return;
};

ConnectUtils.loadQuery = function(connection, options = {}) {
  ensure.notNull(connection.base.DriverName, 'connection driver name');
  ensure.notNull(connection.base.Database, 'connection database');
  ensure.notNull(options.tableName, 'table name');
  const table = options.tableName;
  const filePath = ConnectUtils.getOutputFilePath(table, options);
  if (connection.base.DriverName === DATABASE_JS_TYPE[MYSQL]) {
    return `LOAD DATA INFILE \'${filePath}\' INTO TABLE ${
      connection.base.Database
    }.${table} FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;`;
  } else if (connection.base.DriverName === DATABASE_JS_TYPE[POSTGRES]) {
    return `COPY ${table} FROM '${filePath}' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;`;
  }
  return;
};
```

`${filePath}` is path on EC2 instance and `${table}` are the tables on AWS RDS EC2 instance. From your answers before editing my question I assume there is no way to workaround this as this script is trying to reach `${filePath}` as a path on AWS RDS instance. Right?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: There's no way you can access the filesystem on an RDS instance.

Comment: I am not sure you understood me well. I know I can't access filesystem of RDS instance. I am trying to let RDS instance access filesystem of EC2 instance. It can be done from psql CLI by using "\copy" instead of "copy" but I can't manage to do it directly from SQL script executed by Trifacta application.

Comment: The error you show suggests you are using the server-side `COPY` SQL command, not the client-side `\copy` command built into the `psql` CLI tool or an equivalent, which does not require any extra permissions (note that the server never accesses the client's file system; the client just streams the data over the connection, like it would if you ran a bunch of INSERT statements). If you [edit] your question to show the actual code you're using, someone might be able to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: I edited it but now I get it that's probably impossible to do on AWS RDS instance...